# for Java, is Class.newInstance() thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

a part of code like this:

```
class Test {

private static final Map<String, Class> urlHandlers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Class>();
static {
    urlHandlers.put(urlRegexA, HandlerA.class);
    urlHandlers.put(urlRegexB, HandlerB.class);
    ...
}
public Handler handle(String url) {
    ......
    if(url match urlRegex) {
        Class claz = urlHandlers.get(urlRegex);
        //in multi-thread environment, is it thread-safe?
        return claz.newInstance();
    }
}
}
```

I want to known whether Class.newInstance() is thread safe?
anyone know this?

Answer (score 7):

The [javadoc states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)

> The class is instantiated as if by a `new` expression with an empty
>   argument list.

So it is equivalent to doing

```
new YourClass();
```

So it depends entirely on if your `YourClass` constructor is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is thread safe as long as the constructor is not doing anything non-thread safe with the static content of the object.